# Grails remote control - unable to resolve class

Tags: grails

I'm encountering the following error `.../plugins/remote-control-1.5/src/groovy/grails/plugin/remotecontrol/RemoteControlServlet.groovy: 21: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder` when running `grails test-app functional:`

The strange part is that it runs with no problem on one machine but encounters this problem on another machine. I'm using grails V2.4.3 and groovy V2.3.6 and the code is cloned from the same repo onto the two different machines (Mac OS). I've tried clean but the problem still persists.

Why is there a discrepancy between machines? Are there some resident files? How do I do a real "clean" so that all dependencies are downloaded again? Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea about your real problem. But to do a "real" clean, I used to delete ~/.m2, ~/.ivy folders. And also the target folder of the project. (but it is a last measure)

Comment: @Fernando thanks! Deleting the target folder did the trick. If you, post it as an answer, I'll accept it as the solution. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea about your real problem. But to do a "real" clean, I used to delete ~/.m2, ~/.ivy folders. And also the target folder of the project.